# Identify odd aircraft near PWK 7/19/21

Tags: aircraft-identification, canard

My workplace is under the pattern for Chicago Executive (PWK) and we sometimes get interesting/unusual things flying overhead.  Yesterday I heard something that sounded very different from a "normal" aircraft; I looked up and saw a straight-wing prop twin with canard, and what appeared (from below) to be just a thin pipe connecting the fuselage to the empennage (with  horizontal as well as vertical fin).  Maybe like a Piaggio / Diamond crossbreed?  I don't recall whether the props were in front or behind.  Sorry about the sparse description but that's the best I can do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tractor (propellers in front of the wing) or pusher propellers?

Comment: It had both a canard and an aft horizontal tail?  Or does "empennage" just refer to the vertical fin?  Can't quite tell from your description.  Reference to "Piaggio" suggest the former but please clarify--

Comment: I've edited some more detail in.  I don't want to add too much since I fear when I try too hard my brain is adding details I may not have actually seen.  There was a full set of control surfaces aft.  I only got a glimpse for a few seconds.  The engine sound was quite distinctive though -- that's what made me look up.

Comment: Looking at more photos; it might have been a Piaggio.  From some angles the tail might look like an extension aft... https://www.wired.com/images_blogs/autopia/2010/08/Immagine-008-660x440.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this might have been an actual [Diamond Hybrid](https://www.diamondaircraft.com/en/about-diamond/newsroom/news/article/diamond-aircraft-1st-flight-multi-engine-hybrid-electric-aircraft/) -- a combustion/electric hybrid aircraft (hence strange engine sound -- the propellers are driven by electric motors).  The two electric motor nacelles (each holding an electric motor, batteries, and inverter) are mounted on a "canard" type surface (which doesn't appear to have any control surfaces, however) alongside the nose, and the very conventional empennage is on a fairly narrow tail cone.  I presume the combustion engine is inside the nose, as it would be on the conventional Diamond (single engine tractor).